# sudden exporting failure in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Went to export a query in excel format at the end of the day, having exported several over the course of the day (and dozens each week for years), and now I am getting an error. Tried other formats, csv, text, html, delimited etc. with the same results. It writes the file name to the directory, but quits when it gets to the data. Tried SQLcli, same thing. I have shut down, rebooted, tried re-installing, run previous versions, run the current version, run the newest version (sqldeveloper-20.2.0.175.1842), with and without the integrated java environment, to no avail. The detailed error from the most recent version is below:

java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.ExportGenerationOutputStream.closeCurrentStream(ExportGenerationOutputStream.java:537)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.ExportGenerationOutputStream.finished(ExportGenerationOutputStream.java:464)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.ExportAPI$1.doWork(ExportAPI.java:1446)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.export.ExportAPI$1.doWork(ExportAPI.java:1409)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:702)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?
OS is Win 10...

Thanks

Karl

Comment: is that the ENTIRE error stack?

Comment: That is all that is in the "advanced" details section of the error message box, yes... though right now not even that is coming up, it just silently fails. On the logging page now I see "unexpected runtime exception while delivering HashStructureHookEvent"

Answer (score 0):

So it appears I have figured out what was happening: the SQL was too long. It consisted of about 1020 lines of

```
GROUP = 'AAA' AND NBR = '######' OR 
GROUP = 'BBB' AND NBR = '######' OR etc...
```

Running this seems to lock up export, and even though it writes the file name it exports nothing, regardless of which particular version or executable tries to export. With spaces, this came to 44,831 characters, which is beyond the 32,767 Excel cell character limit. Why that matters to csv or other exports formats I cannot say, but the initial export was Excel 2003 format with exported sql, which seemed to hose exporting in general.

Revising the SQL to

```
GROUP = 'AAA' AND NBR IN('######','######',etc...) OR
GROUP = 'BBB' AND NBR IN('######','######',etc...) OR etc...
```

brought the line count down to 126 and the character count to 12,380, and everything now exports fine after logging out and logging back in.

Obviously, the ideal way to have handled this would have been to create a table of the groups and nbrs to link to, but this being a hosted payroll system makes that not an option, so I have to use whatever workaround I can come up with.